# IB complains that a new window has contents that go off screen

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Interface Builder gives me a warning about the set up of my .xib file.

It says, in a dialog called "MainMenu.xib Info",

> Object: Window
> ID: 21
> Type: Illegal Configuration
> Issue: This window's content rectangle does not lie entirely on the screen with the menu bar and may not be completely visible for all screen resolutions and configurations.

I'm using XCode Version 3.1.2 and Interface Builder version 3.1.2 (677).  I verified that I could recreate the issue by creating a new Core Data Application and opening the .xib file.  Also interesting is that when I open the .xib file, the main window does not display right away (as it does with other templates), but will come up when I double-click on its representation in the window with the File's Owner, First Responder, etc.  It has nothing visible in it (it does have a Content View inside it), and the Inspector shows the size as 213 x 107 (px?).

I see that there is a 3.1.3 version out now, and it does look like a bug in either Interface Builder or the template for a Core Data Application, but, is there any way for me to fix this?  Resizing the window doesn't help, and it is not at all clear to me under what conditions the errors and warnings come up (ie. if I have to compile, or if they change just as soon as I adjust the UI.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Easily fixed.

In Interface builder select the window and then from the inspector go to the window size tab and move the window away from the left edge. This will get rid of the warning.